# Мобильная версия Prestashop 1.6

Tags: mobile

Как создать мобильную версию сайта?

Изначально в теме была пустая папка `mobile`, после того как скопировала все файлы `tpl` и `css` сайт на мобильниках стал отображаться иначе, но когда я меняю файлы в папке `mobile` ничего не изменяется, а когда в основной версии шаблона - на мобильном изменяется. Никак не могу разобраться как это работает.

Мобильная версия сайта внешне должна очень отличаться и половина модулей в мобильной версии должно быть отключено, хотя когда я ставлю в свойствах модуля - блокировать на смартфонах, модуль все равно отображается на мобильном устройстве..

Comment: Bootstrap twiter попробуй

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а есть варианты сделать без bootstrap? Просто как я поняла, если мне внедрять в тему bootstrap, то придется переписывать почти всю тему